# UITableView Custom Cells Disappearing content after Scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have seen this being asked here many times but none of the solutions worked for me. Here is my code snippet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellClassName = @"DemoTableViewCell_sched";
    DemoTableViewCell_sched *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.fooData = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}
```

Then I have in `ViewDidLoad`

```
    cellLoader = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DemoTableViewCell_sched" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: Did you check that in your cell you are specify the identifier?

Comment: Yes. In the custom cell I made sure the identifier is "DemoTableViewCell_sched." What else should I check?

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36037259/4034301) worked for me.Great solution..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem went away when either:

1. The table view contains many cells (10+),
2. Each cell has a height of more than 50.

Weird.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, what was happening was that I had not kept a strong pointer to the tableview's dataSource. So when the tableview was scrolled, the datasource had already been freed and set to nil, which led to the tableview getting 0 for numRowsForSection and nils for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

If anyone has a similar problem, you might look if your datasource and/or custom objects are retained properly.

Answer (score 14):

Are you adding the UITableViewcontroller as addSubView ?
Then you should do like this :

```
1) addChildViewController,then
2) addSubview
The problem is delegate and datasource of the tableview getting nil since the parent controller unable to a reference to the UITableViewController.
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was the following:

1. I had a special case where view controller's view was not pushed or presented modally but I've added it as a subview (view.addSubview) to another view.
2. This way the actual view was retained by its superview, but ViewController object (which was DataSource for table view) was not retained and went out of memory.
3. I had to assign view controller to a (strong) variable so it stayed in memory.

Comment: Only cause I was nesting Table view in Container view, had the same problem. Solved with assigning Controller to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an answer, but just for googlers:

In my case the problem was that the views were still in the `UITableViewCell` but after scrolling due to a mistake in the `frame` property of the views, they went under the next `UITableViewCell` and I could not see them.

I think as the accepted answer has clearly said that :

> The problem went away when either:
>
> - The table view contains many cells (10+),
> - Each cell has a height of more than 50.

he had similar problem to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have implemented heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and also make sure that your constraints are properly set.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue several times. It is very disturbing since it might be anything. From wrong layout constraints to much serious problems.
In first case: in *UITableViewCell* I had

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

After removing this line everytnig went to normal.

In seconds case: I had wrong layout constraint set programmatically:

```
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16)
```

The stack element supposed to be set to Top, not to Bottom. After fixing this line everything went normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,because I have override this function:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
//    frame.origin.y += 10;
//    frame.size.height -= 10;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the correct height for each cells according to its content.

This can be done in the UITableView delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       CGFloat height;
       //Calculate height for each cell
       return height;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This behavior in TableView had got me head banging literally. Turns out I had used

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *itemsArray;
```

instead of

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *itemsArray;
```

Hope this information helps.

Comment: not really helps . If I scroll down , the cell still regenerates and display wrong UI

Comment: for starters, check what data is passed from the NSArray/NSDictionary that you are using while returning the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, may be check the constraints again (in regards to frame & bounds in code) or Autolayout settings. Also consider down voting @wcobbett answer as well, as I just wrote that in code to avoid reading lengthy answers & be specify about what problem you are facing either in theory or in code.